# How to fill info in a popup window in a shell script?

Tags: shell, git, window

This is the usually commands that I use to deploy:

```
cd app
npm run build
cd ..
git push azure_3 master:master
```

The last commands opens a popup window, where I have to enter a password:

[image]

But I don't know how to fill it from the shell script (or via Git).

What the usual solution for these cases?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a password. Generate an SSH key and push it to your remote server: the one where you log in with user **staging1234**.

Check if you have a public key `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (the .ssh folder is located into the user@User-PC **home** folder.

If you already have a public ssh key append that one into the 
`.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the remote server.

You can do this *manually* via copy/paste

...Or *programmatically* via:

`ssh-copy-id staging1234@your-azure-server`

If you don't have a public key generate one with: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048`

This way you will end up logging in directly on your remote Azure server: you have a public key, generated by you and stuck on your remote server, which you can think as a *closed door*, and a private key the one you need to keep secret and that open SSH use safely to open that *door*.